# Disambiguate overloaded methods that accept different functional interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following available methods in a `Utils` class:

```
protected <U> U withTx(Function<OrientGraph, U> fc) {
    // do something with the function
}

protected void withTx(Consumer<OrientGraph> consumer) {
    withTx(g -> {
        consumer.accept(g);
        return null;
    });
}
```

And in a method of `myClass` I have:

```
withTx(g -> anotherMethod(g));
```

The second piece of code has a compilation error:

`The method withTx(Function<OrientGraph, Object>) is ambiguous for the type myClass`

I guess this comes from the compiler, which is not able to determine if the lambda is a `Consumer` or a `Function`. Is there a noble way to disambiguate this situation?

Whatever the method `anotherMethod` returns (`void`, `Object`, anything), I don't want to use this return value.

One solution is to do:

```
withTx(g -> { anotherMethod(g); });
```

But I wanted to know if there was something better, because this triggers `SonarLint`.

Comment: what is the return type of `anotherMethod()`? Are you saying that `withTx(g -> anotherMethod());` doesn't compile but `withTx(g -> { anotherMethod(); });` does?

Comment: The solution should work with any return type. If you really want an answer, let's say it returns `Object`. That's why I am saying yes

Comment: this was asked actually *multiple* times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the *"Effective Java"* by Joshua Bloch:

> Do not provide a method with multiple overloadings that take different
>   functional interfaces in the same argument position if it could create
>   a possible ambiguity in the client.
>
> The easiest way to avoid this problem is not to write overloadings
>   that take different functional interfaces in the same argument
>   position.

One more possible solution could be to use a different names for these two methods:

```
<U> U withTxFunction(Function<OrientGraph, U> fc);

void withTxConsumer(Consumer<OrientGraph> consumer);
```

A good example of this approach one can find in the `Java API` itself, for example in the  [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) interface:

```
mapToDouble(IntToDoubleFunction mapper);

mapToLong(IntToLongFunction mapper);
```

**Update:**

I'd like to add a clarification of why does the compiler complain? That is because...

The lambda `g -> anotherMethod(g)` can be assigned to both `Function<T, R>` and `Consumer<T>`:

```
Function<T, R> func  = g -> anotherMethod(g);

Consumer<T> consumer = g -> anotherMethod(g); // here you just ignore the return value

<T> T anotherMethod(T t) { ... }
```

So, when you write `withTx(g -> anotherMethod(g))`, you get the *"Ambiguous method call"* error, the compiler fails to find out which of the overloaded method should be used:

```
withTx(function) OR withTx(consumer) ... ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you already have the resolution to your problem, but in a different place, because you write:

```
withTx(g -> {
    consumer.accept(g);
    return null; // this calls the `Function` variant of `withTx`
});
```

But anyways, you have this problem because the return type of your function `anotherMethod()` is `void`, and the compiler doesn't know what to choose from, the `Function<OrientGraph, Void>` or `Consumer<OrientGraph>`. `Consumer` itself is supposed to represent a function that accepts something and returns nothing.

`withTx(g -> { anotherMethod(g); });` calls the `Consumer` variant explicitly.

If you want to call the `Function` variant, do:
`withTx(g -> { anotherMethod(g); return null; });`